# How to send posts requests to contact form 7 from React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, contact-form-7

I.m currently making a React front end website using Wordpress as a backend. I've managed to set `user authentication` using **JWT** and i'm now trying to send post requests to Contact Form 7 and i'm having trouble converting the form tags to `json` and don't really know where to start and i'm not entirely sure that this is the correct process to be following.

I'm using `axios` to send posts requests and the websites are still running locally (i understand i might have **CORS** issues and trouble actually sending the form to an email but i want to get it to a point where all the data is getting sent over correctly).

Below is the code to my **Contact component**.

Current errors:
[Console Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1uei.png)

React Geniuses Please Help :)....

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

class Contact extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props) 
            this.state = {
                yourName: '',
                yourEmail: '',
                subject: '',
                message: '',
                successMessage:'',
                loading: false,
                error: ''
            }
    }

    onFormSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        const siteURL = 'http://localhost/wordpress'
        const formData = {
            yourName: this.state.yourName,
            yourEmail: this.state.yourEmail,
            subject: this.state.subject,
            message: this.state.message
        }

        this.setState({ loading:true}, () => {
            axios.post(`${siteURL}/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/92/feedback`, formData)
            .then( res => {
                this.setState({loading: false, successMessage: 'Yay your message was sent'})
                console.warn( res.data)
            })
            .catch( err => {
                           this.setState({ error: err.response.data, loading: false})
                       })
        })
    }

    handleOnChange = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value})
    }

    render() {
        const { yourName, yourEmail, subject, message, successMessage} = this.state
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
            <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} style={{ margin: '20px'}}>
                <label className='form-group'>
                  Name:
                  <input 
                   type='text'
                   className="form-control"
                   name='yourName'
                   value={yourName}
                   onChange={this.handleOnChange}
                  ></input>
                </label>
                <br />
                <label className='form-group'>
                Email:
                <input 
                 type='text'
                 className="form-control"
                 name='yourEmail'
                 value={yourEmail}
                 onChange={this.handleOnChange}
                ></input>
                </label>
                <br />
                <label className='form-group'>
                Subject:
                <input 
                 type='text'
                 className="form-control"
                 name='subject'
                 value={subject}
                 onChange={this.handleOnChange}
                ></input>
                </label>
                <br />
                <div className="form-group">
                <label className="form-group"> Message:</label>
                <textarea 
                 type='textarea'
                 className="form-control"
                 name='message'
                 value={message} 
                 onChange={this.handleOnChange}
                 rows="3"
                ></textarea>
                </div>
  <br />
  <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary'>Login</button>
<h1>{successMessage}</h1>                
                </form>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
export default Contact
```

Contact Form 7 Layout:

```
<label> Your Name (required)
    [text* your-name] </label>

<label> Your Email (required)
    [email* your-email] </label>

<label> Subject
    [text your-subject] </label>

<label> Your Message
    [textarea your-message] </label>

[submit "Send"]
```

Ok so i've made a little progress with this, the below comment is true and the formatting needs to be in 'your-name': format.

You also have to be authenticated to send a post request to the contact form which i found a little strange because aren't forms suppose to be used by everyone?

I am now getting the post request to authenticate here's my code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'



class Contact extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props) 

            this.state = {
                yourName: '',
                yourEmail: '',
                subject: '',
                message: '',
                successMessage:'',
                loading: false,
                error: ''
            }
        
    }

    onFormSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
       

        const siteURL = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://thedigiweb.uk'

       

      const formData = {
        
               'your-name':
             this.state.yourName,
             'your-email': 
            this.state.yourEmail,
             'your-subject':
             this.state.subject,
            'your-message' :
            this.state.message,

        


        }

     
        console.log(formData)
    
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        this.setState({ loading: true}, () => {
            axios.post(`${siteURL}/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/55/feedback`, 
            {formData}, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            })
            .then( res => {
                this.setState({loading: false, successMessage: res.data.message})
                console.warn( res.data)
            })
           

            .catch( err => {
                           this.setState({ error: 'you have an error', loading: false})
                           
                       })
        })

    }


    handleOnChange = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()

        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value})

       

    }

    render() {
       
        const { yourName, yourEmail, subject, message, successMessage} = this.state
        return(
            <React.Fragment>

            <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} style={{ margin: '20px'}}>
   
                <label className='form-group'>
                  Name:
                  <input 
                  type='text'
                  className="form-control"
                  name='yourName'
                  value={yourName}
                  onChange={this.handleOnChange}
                  
   
                  ></input>
                
                </label>
                <br />
                <label className='form-group'>
                Email:
                <input 
                type='text'
                className="form-control"
                name='yourEmail'
                value={yourEmail}
                onChange={this.handleOnChange}
   
                ></input>
                
                </label>
                <br />
                <label className='form-group'>
                Subject:
                <input 
                type='text'
                className="form-control"
                name='subject'
                value={subject}
                onChange={this.handleOnChange}
   
                ></input>
                
                </label>
                <br />
               
                <div className="form-group">
                <label className="form-group"> Message:</label>
               
                <textarea 
                type='textarea'
                className="form-control"
                name='message'
                value={message} 
                onChange={this.handleOnChange}
                rows="3"
            
                ></textarea>

                
                
                
                </div>
  <br />
  
  <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>


<h1>{successMessage}</h1>
                
                
                </form>
            
            
            
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}


export default Contact
```

The only thing now is that the email isn't getting sent, it's working fine through PostMan and i don't need any token to send the form either.

if anyone feels like joining in on this it would be appreciated, i'm sure there's and easy fix to all this.

Answer (score 1):

Just thought i'd come back and update this, here's a modal using mdbreact and wordpress contact form 7 via the rest api.

```
 import React, { Component } from "react"
import {
MDBContainer,
MDBModal,
MDBModalBody,
MDBModalHeader,
MDBModalFooter,
MDBRow,
MDBCol,
MDBBtn,
MDBIcon,
MDBInput,
} from "mdbreact"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import axios from "axios"
import classes from "./Contact.module.css"

export default class Contact extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.state = {
    name: "",
    email: "",
    contactNumber: "",
    postcode: '',
    message: "",
    isOpen: false,
    messageSent: "",
    errorMessage: "",
  }
}

toggleModal = () => {
  this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen }, () => {
    window.scroll({top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' })
    this.state.isOpen ? document.body.classList.add(classes.BodyClass) : document.body.classList.remove(classes.BodyClass)
  })
}

onChangeHandler = e => {
  this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })

  console.log(e.target.value)
}

onSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault()

  let formData = new FormData()

  formData.set("your-name", this.state.name)
  formData.set("your-email", this.state.email)
  formData.set("your-number", this.state.contactNumber)
  formData.set("your-message", this.state.message)
  formData.set("your-postcode", this.state.postcode)

  axios
    .post(
      `your url here`,
      formData,
      {
        headers: {
          "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      }
    )
    .then(res => {
      res.data.status === "mail_sent"
        ? this.setState({ 
          messageSent: res.data.message,
          name: "",
          email: "",
          contactNumber: "",
          postcode: '',
          message: "",

         })
        : this.setState({ errorMessage: res.data.message }, () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.setState({ errorMessage: "" })
            }, 2000)
          })
    })
}

render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <MDBContainer className={classes.BtnCon}>
        <span onClick={this.toggleModal} className={classes.Link}>
          Contact Us
        </span>
      </MDBContainer>
      <MDBModal
        isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
        toggle={this.toggleModal}
        className={classes.Modal}
      >
        <MDBModalHeader
          className={classes.ModalHead}
          toggle={this.toggleModal}
        >
          Get In Touch
          <br />

        </MDBModalHeader>
        <MDBModalBody>
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} className={classes.Form}>
            <div className="grey-text">
              <MDBInput
                label="Your name"
                icon="user"
                group
                type="text"
                name="name"
                value={this.state.name}
                validate
                error="wrong"
                success="right"
                onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
                className={classes.Input}
              />
              <MDBInput
                label="Your email"
                name="email"
                value={this.state.email}
                icon="envelope"
                group
                type="email"
                validate
                error="wrong"
                success="right"
                onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
                className={classes.Input}
              />
              <MDBInput
                label="Contact Number"
                name="contactNumber"
                value={this.state.contactNumber}
                icon="phone"
                group
                type="tel"
                validate
                error="wrong"
                success="right"
                onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
                className={classes.Input}
              />
              <MDBInput
                label="Postcode"
                name="postcode"
                value={this.state.postcode}
                icon="home"
                group
                type="text"
                validate
                error="wrong"
                success="right"
                onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
                className={classes.Input}
              />

              <MDBInput
                type="textarea"
                name="message"
                value={this.state.message}
                rows="2"
                label="Your message"
                icon="pencil-alt"
                onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
                className={classes.InputMessage}
              />
            </div>
            {this.state.messageSent && (
              <p className="success-color text-white text-center">
                {this.state.messageSent}
              </p>
            )}
            {this.state.errorMessage && (
              <p className="danger-color-dark text-white text-center">
                {this.state.errorMessage}
              </p>
            )}
            <div className="text-center">
              <MDBBtn className={classes.FormBtn} type="submit">
                Send <MDBIcon far icon="paper-plane" className="ml-1" />
              </MDBBtn>
            </div>
          </form>
        </MDBModalBody>
        <MDBModalFooter>
          <MDBBtn color="black" onClick={this.toggleModal}>
            Close
          </MDBBtn>
        </MDBModalFooter>
      </MDBModal>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
}
```

Comment: I came to find that the issue was with passing the form data in my case and what fixed it for me what I found in your answer namely:
```js
  let formData = new FormData()

  formData.set("your-name", this.state.name)
  formData.set("your-email", this.state.email)

 ``` Upvoted!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your'e not sending the correct keys with your values up.

From the source code for contact form 7, they access the posted values like:

`$posted_data['your-email']`

So try switching from camelCase to kebab-case, and keep message and subject like they have.

So your formData should be like:

```
const formData = {
            'your-name': this.state.yourName,
            'your-email': this.state.yourEmail,
            'your-subject': this.state.subject,
            'your-message': this.state.message
        }
```

Comment: Hi this still didn't work when i changed the required field in wordpress to false it's saying the message has been sent but it still doesn't work.  Link to current build http://makemeareactsitetest-com.stackstaging.com/

Comment: Ah try adding this to your request? I think you need to send as multip part / form data.
So:
``axios.post(
`${siteURL}/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/92/feedback`,
formData,
{ headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
  } }
)``

Comment: Hi mate, i've put it on a live domain name at https://moderncleaningsolutions.co.uk i got it working the first way you said but the email never reaches the mailbox for some reason. I'm getting the success message but nothing comes through.

Comment: @Tjs90 I think that might be an issue from your WordPress contact form 7 mail setup, Choose the form you are trying to use and go to the mail tab and fix your settings. Note that the mail from has to be the same domain as your WordPress site domain e.g info@your-site.domain